# Android Developer Console and Google Play statistics, updates and sync?

Tags: android, google-play

I read somewhere that app info on Android Developer Console is updated daily at 09:00 (what timezone?).

However I know that several people have installed my app and the number of installs is still "-".

I have gotten one review and it was shown directly after the review was done but no install is shown.

Also, the review is not shown on Google Play, aren't these the same? Don't they sync?

Does any of this have to be enabled? Like ANRs, how is that data sent to my account, user has to approve email or is it sent automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Depends where you live.My stat updates around 11PM every day.And also the counters are not correct.I dont trust them :D.Just wait a bit and it will update normally.